# How can I specify execution directory for Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, extjs, sencha-cmd

I updated the original question by adding the following, which solves the issue:

```
<workingDirectory>src/main/extApps/usx</workingDirectory>
```

I am executing Sencha Cmd in Maven, but the pom file is not in the application directory, where the tool needs to execute.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.atlantis.amc.AmcWebApp</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sencha-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>sencha</executable>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/extApps/usx</workingDirectory>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>app</argument>
                    <argument>build</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another way:

```
<arguments>
    <argument>-sdk</argument>
    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/extApps/usx</argument>
    <argument>app</argument>
    <argument>build</argument>
    <argument>--clean</argument>
    <argument>--environment</argument>
    <argument>production</argument>
    <argument>--destination</argument>
    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/extApps/usx/build</argument>
</arguments>
```

Parameters explanation:

```
$ sencha help app build
```